# My table is not mapped when using modifying and query annotations?

Tags: java, spring-boot, annotations, mapping

I am using @Modifying and @Query annotations to execute my sql statement directly, but I am getting an error, telling me that my table in not mapped, so I dont know what I am doing wrong, Here is my code :

```
@Repository
public interface TypesContratDaoJPA extends CrudRepository<Type, Long> {

    @Query("select type_id from declaration_type where declaration_id=:declaration")
    List<Integer> getListTypes(@Param("declaration") int declaration);

    @Modifying
    @Query("insert into declaration_type values(:declaration,:type)")
    void addTypeToContrat(@Param("declaration") int declaration, @Param("type") int type);

    @Modifying
    @Query("delete from declaration_type where declaration_id=:declaration and type_id=:type")
void deleteTypeFromContrat(@Param("declaration") int declaration, @Param("type") int type);

}
```

I get this error :

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: declaration_type is not mapped [delete from declaration_type where declaration_id=:declaration and type_id=:type]
at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:133)
at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:157)
at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:164)
at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:670)
at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:23)

...
... 
... 
...
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: which database? and table `declaration_type` is in public schema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want to execute a native query instead of a JPQL one.

In order to mark the queries as native you should add `nativeQuery = true` as a property on he `@Query` annotation.
For example your first query should look like this:

```
@Query("select type_id from declaration_type where declaration_id=:declaration", nativeQuery = true)
    List<Integer> getListTypes(@Param("declaration") int declaration);
```

If you don't add `nativeQuery = true` in the query annotation, the query is considered a JPQL query.
So, in order to make your first query work, you will have to have a class named `declaration_type` that is annotated with the `@Entity` and has fields that are named `declaration_id` and `type_id`.
You should checkout some JPQL tutorial (or the documentation) in order to learn more about these type of queries.

Comment: Yes, That was it, Thanks